# RecyclerView interface for onclicklinester not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**Pleas can someone tell me why onSelect is not working when i click in something?
i passed many hours trying to solve this but cant find a good solution**

RecyclerView fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.recyclerviewCriptomoedasMenu.adapter = CryptoCardListAdapter(
            cryptoCards(),
            object : CryptoCardListAdapter.OnSelectOnClickListener {
                override fun onSelect(position: Int) {
                    when (cryptoCards()[position].coinTitle) {
                        "Bitcoin" -> {
                            val direction =
                                InvestimentosFragmentDirections.actionInvestimentosFragmentToAddFragment(
                                    cryptoCards()[position]
                                )
                            findNavController().navigate(direction)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            val direction =
                                InvestimentosFragmentDirections.actionInvestimentosFragmentToAddFragment(
                                    cryptoCards()[position]
                                )
                            findNavController().navigate(direction)
                        }
                    }
                }

            })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to detect your problem while lacking of your adapter implementation for the `onSelect` callback inside the listener. But there are some samples for handling on item click for Recyclerview that you can reference.

From [Udacity](http://%20https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-with-recyclerview)

From official [Android](https://github.com/android/sunflower)

Comment: I cant post the complete code, stack dont let me